# Error: Editor' is not exported from 'slate-react'

Tags: reactjs, slate, react-slate

I'm trying to build simple slate editor in React.

I'm using create-react-app and I have made simple component for representing the editor

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Editor } from "slate-react";
import { Value } from "slate";

const SlateEditor = () => {    
const initialValue = Value.fromJSON({
  document: {
    nodes: [
      {
        object: 'block',
        type: 'paragraph',
        nodes: [
          {
            object: 'text',
            leaves: [
              {
                text: 'A line of text in a paragraph.',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
})

    const [ value, setValue ] = useState(initialValue)
    return (
        <div>
            <Editor className = "Editor" value={value} onChange= {(e)=>setValue(e.value)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default SlateEditor;
```

This is my package json file

```
{
  "name": "slate-editor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.15",
    "is-hotkey": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "slate": "^0.66.1",
    "slate-plain-serializer": "^0.7.13",
    "slate-react": "^0.66.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have error
Failed to compile.

> ./src/components/SlateEditor.js Attempted import error: 'Editor' is not
> exported from 'slate-react'

As you can see I exported Editor from slate-react, please any idea how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Please import Editor from slate and not slate-react

Answer (score 0):

slate-react does not export Editor, you can import Editor from 'slate', or use the Slate and Editable components as shown in the documentation https://docs.slatejs.org/walkthroughs/01-installing-slate